# Regex to accept specific file types

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-file-upload

I am using the [BlueImp jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) and on its manual, regex code is required to fill the accepted file types you want to upload. I have here the regex so far:

```
/^image\/(gif|jpe?g|png)$|^application\/(csv|pdf|msword)$|^text\/plain$/i;
```

But that doesn't support other file types such as docx. What I want are the following file types:

```
doc,docx,xls,xlsx,ppt,pptx,jpg,png,gif,pdf,txt,csv
```

Comment: add all the above file types inside the capturing group.

Comment: If you wrote that kind of regex you should be able to add those file types yourself. So I suspect you *didn't* write that regex. That means you should say where you got it from.

Comment: I didn't. I got it from the official manual of the blueimp jquery file upload. i thought 'msword' keyword in the regex includes the docx but it doesn't.

Comment: Good thought, but the common mime type for .docx files isn't `application/msword` (that's `.doc`), but `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` Here are the others: http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modern MS Office mime types are different from the old-fashioned ones. So when it used to be `application/msword`, it now is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`.

There are quite a few specific mime types now, but they all start with `vnd.` and then it's either `ms-` or `openxmlformats-`.

So, adding mime types that catch all possible modern Office file types would reflect that:

```
/^image\/(gif|jpe?g|png)$|^application\/(csv|pdf|msword|(vnd\.(ms-|openxmlformats-).*))$|^text\/plain$/i;
//-----------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Other mime types are listed here. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309278%28v=office.12%29.aspx